# Multiprocessing of multiple looping scripts in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I am trying to run multiple Python scripts, containing while loops, at the same time. As an example, I am using a `config.json` file that tracks if bots should be running and if they are actually running. The `main.py` file contains an infinite loop with a condition that is true after I manually save the config of a file by setting `should_run` to `true`. If the condition is met, it should launch a script, like `file1.py` or `file2.py`, and then continue the loop. However, the loop doesn't continue and a second script can not launched at the same time.

## Config.json

```
{"file1.py": {"should_run": false, "running": false},
 "file2.py": {"should_run": false, "running": false}}
```

## main.py:

```
import json
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def load_and_run_script(script):
    exec(open(script).read())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    config_filename = 'config.json'
    process_dict = {}

    while True:

        with open(config_filename, 'r') as f:
            cfg = json.load(f)
    
        for key, value in list(cfg.items()):
            if value['should_run'] and not value['running']:
                process = Process(target=load_and_run_script(key))
                process_dict[key] = process
                process.start()
                cfg[key]['running'] = True

        with open(config_filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(cfg, f)

        time.sleep(5)
```

## file1.py and file2.py:

```
import time
import __main__ as main

counter = 0
while True:
    counter += 1
    print(f'filename: {main.__file__}, counter : {counter}')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: A fundamentally different solution is also fine as long as it solves the problem.

Comment: you are calling `load_and_run_script` in the main process and passing it's return value to `target`. Instead call `Process(target=load_and_run_script, args=(key,))`. This `load_and_run_script` however is a very roundabout way of executing a script where you could simply just move the code into a function and import it in main, then pass it as the `target`